# Is it possible to test bluetooth applications with iphone simulator running on top of vmware?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I have Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 installed on my vmware virtual machine running on Windows 7. XCode version is 4.0.

Is it possible to test bluetooth applications with iphone simulator or does the iPhone simulator in XCode support bluetooth?

Comment: Isn't it against apple policies to run mac os in a vmware ?

Answer (score 0):

On a mac it would work, however with the current setup, it is not going to - and as pointed out by @EvilP it against various copyright agreements.